# "Load" function not setting variable

Tags: javascript, variables, local-storage

I have two functions that save variables to LocalStorage. The first one saves a variable, "money", but the second doesn't. The global variable "money" does not get assigned.

```
function saveVars() {
    localStorage.setItem('money', money);
}

function loadVars() {
    var money = localStorage.getItem('money');
}
```

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: no error in console

Comment: what is `console.log(money)` shows?

Comment: console.log money (i put this is console)
VM56:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Comment: Do you need local variable only in loadVars? It is accessible only in the function, maybe here is the problem

Comment: This money variable is supposed to exist outside of the function as well.

Comment: @charliestg — No, it isn't. You need to understand what `var` does.

Comment: All the `var` declarations at the top of your file declare global variables. That means the variables are available anywhere in the code, unless there is a variable with the same name and a more specific scope (that would be "shadowing" the global variable).

Comment: The reason those declarations declare *global* variables is because they occur in a global context (not inside a function body). The keyword `var` itself doesn't have anything to do with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your example, I can assume two alternatives :

1) you want to "load" the value into a *global* variable named "money" ? Your code doesn't work because you declare a *local* variable "money" that only exists within the function `loadVars`. Don't declare your variable (i.e. do not add the keyword `var` or any equivalent in the function). The assignment `money = …` will assign to the global variable "money" only if there is no other variable named "money" in a more specific scope — and it will do so even if the global variable was not declared.

```js
function loadVars() {
    money = localStorage.getItem('money');
}
```

2) you want `loadVars` to *return* the value of the stored variable ? and then you can assign that to a global:

```js
function loadVars() {
    return localStorage.getItem('money');
}

var money = loadVars();
```

Comment: It is supposed to save to a local variable, how would I incorporate this answer into my code? I am a bit of a rookie at JS, and don't really understand.

Comment: This money variable is supposed to exist outside of the function as well.

Comment: First: "saving to a local variable" makes no sense in programming. "Saving" usually means saving to some persistent storage outside of the runtime memory. What you do is "assign" values to variables.

Comment: Now that we've cleared up the semantics, if a variable should exist outside of a function, then it can't be local to that function. Hence, you probably want a global, as I suggested.

Comment: Now, I need to assign a variable that exists outside of the function (but existing inside the "app.js" file.) (again, I am a noob at this)

Comment: Yes, I got that you're new to programming and JavaScript and I think I understand the goal. Is the concept of "global" variable still unclear ?

Comment: Yeah, what is the concept of a global variable?

Comment: Fixed it, removed the "var" from the function